# Why facebook.php does not work?

Tags: php, facebook, interface

I am trying to use facebook API and some functions/objects used in tutorials are NOT defined in facebook.php (downloaded from github.com). 
Am I so silly or is there some other think I should know?

Thanks for help,

Roman

Answer (score 1):

Just for your attention: Facebook has changed its whole API structure last week, and their documentation is still in a state of transition.

Make sure you start out from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ to get only the new version of the API (it is much better than the old one, by the way).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I started at developers.facebook.com. The API I have was downloaded from facebook official site (github.com ?) this morning... maybe they changed the site meanwhile...:)

Comment: Just to verify, you downloaded from "http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/"? Maybe the functions/objects you tried to use are from the outdated API version? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, that was the address I used for download. Probably, the tutorial was old, the downloaded api is probably the new one. I was trying to use non-existing object api_client or function require_login() ...

Comment: still there are issues with their examples, so you can't rely to much on them

Answer (score 0):

Because they have updated/changed their API recently, try browsing facebook developers section, you'll find the necessary changes there

Answer (score 0):

That's most probably because you are using old facebook client which does not have functions that are in the new php client such as `streamPublish`, etc. You need to download the latest facebook PHP client.

Comment: Tanks for answer, but I downloaded it an hour ago from official site (github.com?). Is there some other reliable site for download? I talk about object like api_client or function like require_login() etc...

Comment: @Roman: i am not sure whether the one at gitlub is new one and unfortunately, it is hard finding the latest version of it. I would suggest you to google about it.

Comment: Safraz, I spend the whole last night with google instead of my girlfriend :) But I dont give up! Thanks.